# generation of random numbers

Tags: java, random

I would like to randomly generate 10 numbers (0 or 1), it means that the result will look like (for example) 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0; 
 My question is how to resolve the following situation:

- I want that the percentage of having 1 is 70% which means that I will have 7 times the number 1 and 3 times the number 0

  For example:
  we suppose that 0 is for false response and 1 is for a true one, if I have 100 responses, the percentage of having true responses is X % and the percentage of having false responses is Y %, so I want generate such a numbers, according to the percentage that I want, some time I need that the trues responses should be = 80% and the false one= 20% for example, and other time I need that false responses=40% and true responses=60%....

Comment: I don't get the 25%, then 40% etc. bit - what pattern does it follow?

Comment: Case A doesn't sound particularly random.

Comment: -1 question is changing, meaning is unknown.  voting to close

Comment: 70% chance of having a 1 doesn't mean you'll actually get the number 1 7/10 times...

Answer (score 3):

You'd essentially approach this by generating a random number in a greater range, say up to 100 - then picking a number out of that range which gave you your percentage.

So:

```
int num;
Random rand = new Random();
int result = rand.nextInt(100);
if(result<70) {
    //70% chance this would happen
    num = 1;
}
else {
    //30% chance this would happen
    num = 0;
}
```

...and so on. If you need a number set based on these probabilities, you'd just define it separately and initialise it in the if statements above (which would depend on the outcome of the random number.)

If however you want the same amount of numbers but just in a different order, then just create an array containing those numbers and shuffle it.

Comment: This answer is wrong, because what happens if result is 80?

Comment: @ckuetbach then nothing would happen. That doesn't make the answer wrong however unless there's something else I missed, since I stated in the if statements that there's only a 25% chance one would happen and a 40% that the other would. This only makes 65%, so there's a 35% chance in the example nothing will happen at all!

Comment: I've edited the answer just to complete it anyway though :)

Comment: But the percentage to get a 0 is not 25% and the percentage to get a 1 is not 40%. In fact the question change a little bit, right now, I guess you would give a different answer.

Comment: @ckuetbach yeah.. the original question did seem to state that he wanted a 25% then 40% chance... now it's changed entirely.

Comment: Edited again! Hopefully it won't radically change again...

Comment: Use rand.nextDouble() as I suggested below to support more precise percentage values such as 70.12345%, too. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use an if statement or the `? :` operator.

```
Random rand = new Random();
double chance = 0.25; // Edit to your liking.
int nextbit = (rand.nextDouble() > chance) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Two things wrong with this. 1) The OP wants 70% not 75% 2) This will only generate *on average* 75% `1`s - it won't guarantee *exactly* that percentage...

Comment: Apologies - I see the original question was significantly different to the current question :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to randomly assign to positions within an array. The first 3 assignments are 0 and the remaining 7 will be 1. I don't know Java properly so pseudocode...

```
arr = new int array(10);
set all arr to -1;            // set all to -1 so we know which have not been set

int candidate = rand(10);     // first candidate will be unset so will get a '0'
for loop = 1 to 10 {
  while (arr[candidate]!=-1){ // random candidate until we find an unset position
     candidate = rand(10);
  }
  arr[candidate] = (loop <= 3) ? 0 : 1;  // set first 3 to '0' and rest to '1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is commonly used practice but I saw the following approach in a book:

Define a random int which takes value between 1 <= i <= 10 and after that you can make a switch like following:

```
Random random = new Random();
int count = random.nextInt( 10 ) + 1;
int myNumber; //my random number that will have values 0 or 1

switch ( count )
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
            myNumber = 1;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        myNumber = 0;
        break;
}
```

So, myNumber will have value 1 in 30% of cases and 0 in 70% of cases.

Comment: and who makes shure random.nextInt(10) returns 1 10% of the times, 2 10% of the times and so on ?

Comment: You've got your `1`s and `0`s the wrong way round :) And this will only give *on average* a 70/30% split. The OP wants *exactly* that split...

Answer (score 0):

```
int percentage = 7;
List l = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   if(i<percentage){
      list.add(1);
   } else {
      list.add(0);
   }
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Now you'll have exact 7 times the 1 and 3 times the 0.

Comment: There are faster ways to achieve this though, the general problem of sampling 3 values from a collection of 10 indexes. Also shuffling the remaining 7 objects is unnecessary. ;-)
However, it wasn't clear from the question whether he wants _exactly_ 3 out of 10, or on _average_ 3 out of 10.

Comment: No, it is just an example, we suppose that 0 is for false response and 1 is for a true one, if I have 100 responses, the percentage of having true responses is X% and the percentage of having false responses is Y%, so I want generate such a numbers, according to the percentage that I want, some time I need that the trues responses  should be = 80% and the false one= 20% for example, and another time I need that false responses=50% and true responses=50%....

Answer (score 0):

If you want 7 ones and 3 zeroes, then create a list/array containing 7 ones and 3 zeroes and then shuffle the list/array.

Comment: It seems that you do not understand my question at all!!!!!

Comment: Your question changed a lot before being closed; my method produces a subset of “10 true/false items, each having a 70% chance of being true” which you'd typically want, but at the moment I wrote the answer it seemed that this was what you were asking. It seems you didn't make your question understandable at all.